# Why is the C++ compiler not detecting a properly declared Class?

Tags: c++, boost, wxwidgets, clion, soci

According to the error codes, the compiler (MSVC 2019) is not detecting properly declared classes.

In the following code, the compiler halts at the first mention of `UACvLogin` in the `UACcDefault` class definition.

`[\src\UAC\controllers\UACcDefault.h][1]`:

```cpp
#ifndef MANAGER_UACCDEFAULT_H
#define MANAGER_UACCDEFAULT_H

#include "src/includes.h"
#include "../views/UACvLogin.h"
#include "../models/UACmUsers.h"

//class UACvLogin;
//class UACmUsers;

class UACcDefault {
public:
    UACcDefault();
    UACcDefault(int iMaxLogin, UACmUsers* mUsers = nullptr, UACvLogin* viewLogin = nullptr);
    virtual ~UACcDefault();

    int GetUserid() const;
    void SetUserid(int userid);
    const wxString& GetUsername() const;
    void SetUsername(const wxString& username);
    const wxString& GetPassword() const;
    void SetPassword(const wxString& password);
    int GetContactid() const;
    void SetContactid(int contactid);

    bool GetLoggedIn();

protected:

private:
    UACmUsers* mUsers;
    UACvLogin* viewLogin;
    int iMaxLogin;

};

#endif //MANAGER_UACCDEFAULT_H
```

The error messages are:

```
src/UAC/controllers/UACcDefault.h(19): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'UACvLogin'
src/UAC/controllers/UACcDefault.h(37): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
src/UAC/controllers/UACcDefault.h(37): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
src/UAC/controllers/UACcDefault.h(37): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

I researched the codes, `C2061`, `C2143`, `C4430`, `C2238`, and they indicate the compiler is not detecting that `UACvLogin` has been declared, earlier.

Whenever I take steps to mitigate these errors, such as change the code so `UACvLogin` is not a pointer, I get these error messages:

```
src/UAC/controllers/UACcDefault.h(37): error C3646: 'viewLogin': unknown override specifier
src/UAC/controllers/UACcDefault.h(37): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

The compiler is now focusing on the name (`viewLogin`) of the variable, instead of the type. If I remove `UACvLogin* viewLogin` from the header file (the variable is currently used in only one method), or un-comment the `class UACvLogin;` line, the compiler changes its focus to the `UACmUsers` identifier:

```
src/UAC/controllers/UACcDefault.h(36): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
src/UAC/controllers/UACcDefault.h(36): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
src/UAC/controllers/UACcDefault.h(36): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

If I un-comment *both* class declarations, `class UACvLogin;` and `class UACmUsers;`, the compiler complains about the SOCI library. I will not quote the error messages, here.

I performed a build with the `/P` option to see the preprocessor output and the includes are putting the class declarations where they should be: before they are used/referenced in the the `UACcDefault` class.

Can someone help me find the cause of this error?

---

The entire project is on [GitHub](https://github.com/ptrongithub/Manager).

- [`src\includes.h`](https://github.com/ptrongithub/Manager/blob/development/src/includes.h)
- `../views/UACvLogin.h` = [`src\UAC\views\UACvLogin.h`](https://github.com/ptrongithub/Manager/blob/development/src/UAC/views/UACvLogin.h)
- `../models/UACmUsers.h` = [`src\UAC\models\UACmUsers.h`](https://github.com/ptrongithub/Manager/blob/development/src/UAC/models/UACmUsers.h)
- [`cmake-build-debug-msvc-2019/UACvLogin.i`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ptrongithub/Manager/development/cmake-build-debug-msvc-2019/UACvLogin.i)10.2MB This file shows the preprocessor output for `UACvLogin.cpp`.
- [`cmake-build-debug-msvc-2019/UACmUsers.i`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ptrongithub/Manager/development/cmake-build-debug-msvc-2019/UACmUsers.i)10.2MB This file shows the preprocessor output for `UACmUsers.cpp`.
- [`cmake-build-debug-msvc-2019/UACcDefault.i`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ptrongithub/Manager/development/cmake-build-debug-msvc-2019/UACcDefault.i)10.2MB This file shows the preprocessor output for `UACcDefault.cpp`.

Comment: Does `UACvLogin.h` include `UACcDefault.h`?

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] (with emphasis on the *minimal* part).

Comment: Hard to diagnose the problem without seeing `"../views/UACvLogin.h"`. You say that `UACvLogin` has been properly declared but clearly something is wrong. Have to agree with Nathan this looks suspiciously like cyclic dependencies.

Comment: I looked at the github repo and there is a cyclic dependency with `"UACvLogin.h"` eventually trying to include itself, which is where the problem arises.

Comment: If you look at the preprocessor output file (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ptrongithub/Manager/development/cmake-build-debug-msvc-2019/cUAC.i), `UACvLogin.h` is included only once. Each header file has include guards.

Comment: Code like this seems to be intentionally *should not* include any other files. Just look at it, it has those forward class definitions which you commented out. Remove the includes and it should build fine. Well, leave the first include probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The circular `#includes` came from having a `includes.h`, which also included `main.h`.

The `includes.h` file had everything needed by most of the code: wxWidgets, boost::propertytree, SOCI. Due to needing access to some global variables (preferences), `main.h` was also included.

I have refactored `includes.h` into separate files for each library. Only the models (I am using Model-View-Controller architecture) need access to SOCI.

I have moved the preferences data and methods to a separate class with static members. This cleans up MyApp and eliminates the need to include `main.h`. I am able to stream-line access to each preference setting and reading and writing the preferences data file. Only this class needs access to boost::propertytree.

Answer (score 3):

For a circular include chain, header guards or similar doesn't work as you expect. The problem is that the header file `A.h` needs the symbol `x` from header file `B.h`, and the header file `B.h` needs the symbol `y` from the header file `A.h`. Both can't get their will, some header file will use the symbol from the other file without its header file actually being included (thanks to the include guards).

---

Lets make a simple example, using the names from above...

First header file `A.h`:

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include "B.h"

struct x
{
    y y_member;
};

#endif
```

Then header file `B.h`:

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include "A.h"

struct y
{
    x x_member;
};

#endif
```

Now if we run header file `A.h` through the preprocessor, the resulting code will be something like this:

```
// Included from B.h
struct y
{
    x x_member;
};

// Part of A.h itself
struct x
{
    y y_member;
};
```

Because of the header include guards, the file `B.h` doesn't actually contain any contents from `A.h`, meaning the symbol `x` will be unknown when it's used.

If you remove the header include guards, then you instead have an infinite "recursion" of inclusion, so that won't work either.

---

As I mentioned in a comment you already have the beginnings of the solution yourself. Modify `UACcDefault.h` as follows:

```
#ifndef MANAGER_UACCDEFAULT_H
#define MANAGER_UACCDEFAULT_H

#include "src/includes.h"

// Don't include these header files
// #include "../views/UACvLogin.h"
// #include "../models/UACmUsers.h"

// Do these forward declarations
class UACvLogin;
class UACmUsers;

class UACcDefault {
    // ... Cut to make it shorter
};

#endif //MANAGER_UACCDEFAULT_H
```

And also make sure that the `src/includes.h` file doesn't include the offending files.

You should also make similar edits to the `UACvLogin.h` and `UACmUsers.h` files.

Comment: There are _no_ circular includes. (Preprocessor includes, i.e. `#include`, maybe, but not in the class declarations or class definitions.) Neither `UACmUsers` or `UACvLogin` know about `UACcDefault`. `UACcDefault` does have member data of type `UACmUsers` and `UACvLogin`. All code outside of these classes know about `UACcDefault`, but not the other two classes.

Comment: @JVines Please take a closer look at my example, it shows a typical circular dependency. Do *any* of the header files you have include one of the other files, directly *or indirectly* at any point? (By *indirectly, think of a situation where `A.h` includes `B.h` which includes `C.h` which includes `A.h`, it's the same thing.) If any of the files `UACvLogin.h` or `UACmUsers.h` header files include `UACcDefault.h` you have a circular dependency.

Comment: @JVines And you already have the beginnings of a solution to your own problem with those out-commented forward declarations. Those needs to be "in-commented", and you should *not* include the `UACvLogin.h` and `UACmUsers.h` header files. And those header files should probably not include `UACcDefault.h` as well.

Comment: Look again at your example. You have `class a` with member `b` and `class b` with member `a`. This does not happen in my code. I have class `UACcDefault` with members `UACmUsers` and `UACvLogin`. Class `UACmUsers` does not have members `UACcDefault` or `UACvLogin` and class `UACvLogin` does not have members `UACcDefault` or `UACmUsers`. The includes for `UACvLogin.h` and `UACmUsers.h` must be there. `UACcDefault.h` is the only file that references these two headers (with the exception of `cmakelists.txt`, of course).

Comment: @JVines The first example is only an *example*. And no, do define variables that are pointers to some structure you don't need the full structure, only a forward declaration.

Comment: @JVines And the problem *is* a circular inclusion problem: `UACcDefault.h` includes `UACvLogin.h`, then `UACvLogin.h` includes `includes.h`, then `includes.h` includes `main.h`, which includes `UACcDefault.h`. The solution is what I've showed last in my answer: Don't include the header files, and add the forward declarations.

Comment: I know where the circular `#include`s occur: `UACcDefault.h` includes `includes.h` which in turn includes `main.h` and `main.h` includes `UACcDefault.h`, as well as `includes.h`. `UACcDefault.h` includes `UACmUsers.h` and `UACvLogin.h`. `UACmUsers.h` and `UACvLogin.h` includes `includes.h`, which starts this whole mess over again. Look in the preprocessor output for `UACcDefault.i`: the class definition for `UACvLogin` is pulled in at line 947113. It is *not used* by `UACcDefault` until line 993537.

Comment: @JVines Have you ***tried*** my solution? Does it give the same problem? Some other problem? The error you claim to get is typical for a circular dependency problem. The equally typical solution is to remove header-file inclusion in the offending header file (by the use of forward declaration of the structures used). You of course include the full set of header files in the *source* files.

Comment: Without the headers, it will be ***impossible*** to compile. I did try un-commenting the declarations. The compiler stopped complaining about `UACvLogin` and `UACmUsers`. The new complaints turn out to be SOCI errors, which will be the subject of my next stackoverflow post. I have made changes to the code, which you can see in the GitHub repo, eliminating the need for the declarations. I will describe the changes in my answer.